# Kinect motor control via Processing

Tags: kinect, processing, simple-openni

I'm hacking the Kinect using some simple-openni based processing apps for a talk I plan to give soon and I found an API that appears to control the motor. There is a moveKinect method that appears to be added to the main ContextWrapper interface but I can't seem to get it to work. Looking through the svn history and release notes it appears to have been added last year with a note that explains it doesn't work with the newest drivers(5.1.02,Linux64). I've tried calling the method giving it values in degress and radians but nothing happens. I get no error and no movement. Has anyone else played with this? I'm running with the 2nd to latest processing 2.0 build (the link to processing 2.0.1 doesn't work) and the latest SImpleOpenNI package I could download.

Comment: I've never been able to get it to work either... (have you posted on the Processing Forum and/or the SimpleOpenNI Google Code page btw?)

Answer (score 0):

SimpleOpenNI is the wrapper for OpenNI which allows access to the RGB/IR/Depth streams and the middleware for body/hand detection, but does not allow access to hardware like the LED, accelerometer or motor.

You should try [Kinect P5](http://shiffman.net/p5/kinect/) which uses libfreenect behind the scenes and supports motor control. Bare in mind you won't have support for the middleware.

If you need both middleware and hardware access you can try [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc) with the [ofxOpenNI addon](https://github.com/roymacdonald/ofxOpenNI). It has a has a [hardware class](https://github.com/roymacdonald/ofxOpenNI/blob/master/src/ofxHardwareDriver.h) that works on OSX and Linux (as sudo) allowing use of both the middleware and motor.